Compactness of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$
By Heine-Borel, we know that a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact iff closed and bounded.
Then, immediately, we can say a closed subset of a compact subset $S\subset\mathbb R^n$ is compact.
So far, so good.
My confusion arises when we take an open subset $A$ of a compact set $S\subset \mathbb R^n$. Suppose $\{\mathfrak U_i\}_{i\in \mathfrak I}$, forms an open cover for $A$. We know open sets in $A$ are of form $\mathfrak V\bigcap A$, where $\mathfrak V$ is an open set in $S$.
Assume $\overline{A}=S$. lets take the specific case $A=\{(x,y):0<x,y<1\}\subset \mathbb R^2$ We have $$A\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in\mathfrak I}\mathfrak U_i=\bigcup_{i\in\mathfrak I}(\mathfrak V_i\cap A)$$ 
And $\{\mathfrak V_i\}_{i\in \mathfrak I}$ forms an open cover for $S$. Then being compact it has a finite subcover say $\{\mathfrak V_i\}_{i=1,2,..,n}$, that is $$S\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\mathfrak V_i\Rightarrow A\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\mathfrak V_i\cap A=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\mathfrak U_i$$ implies $A$ is compact, by the definition, every open cover has a finite subcover. But now, by Heine-Borel, $A$ must be closed. Can anyone please explain where the argument went wrong?

You error is in stating that $\mathfrak{B}_i$ forms an open cover of $S$. This is not true. Nothing has been shown about $\mathfrak{B}_i$, save that is can be used to generate an open cover for $A$.

Consider the open cover for $A$ with sets ${(x,y): 0\lt x,y\lt1-1/n}$ with $n=1,2,3,…$

An open cover of the interior doesn't necessarily cover the boundary. Take a concrete example: $A$ = the open unit disc, $S$ = the closed unit disc, and the open cover of $A$ we use is the set of open discs centered at the origin with radii $<1$.
